# How do I retrieve the owners of a Distribution List using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am unsure if I found a bug, or if I am using this the wrong way: I am unable to retrieve the owners of a DL group using Graph.

Steps:

1. Let's assume my email is admin@contoso.com. I created a Distribution List group in the Microsoft 365 Admin Center of my Exchange server, and set myself (the admin) as the owner of that DL. I named this DL "TestDG1". I also added this same user as the sole member of the DL.
2. I then visited the [Graph Explorer website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), logged in as the admin, gave myself Read permissions to access groups, contacts, users, and executed this query:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$filter=startswith(displayName,'TestDG')

I got a successful response with this information:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": null,
            "displayName": "TestDG1",
            "groupTypes": [],
            "mail": "testdg1@contoso.com",
            "mailEnabled": true,
            "mailNickname": "TestDG1",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [
                "SMTP:testdg1@contoso.com"
            ],
            "renewedDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
            "securityEnabled": false,
            "visibility": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": []
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Using the ID of my group (01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF), I checked if I could retrieve that DL's information using:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF

And I got a successful response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "classification": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
    "creationOptions": [],
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "TestDG1",
    "groupTypes": [],
    "mail": "testdg1@contoso.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "TestDG1",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "preferredDataLocation": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:testdg1@contoso.com"
    ],
    "renewedDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
    "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
    "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": null,
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": []
}
```

4. If I request the owners, nothing comes back. I used two methods:

A) Expanding the owners array:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF/?$expand=owners

I get a successful response, but the owners array is empty:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": null,
            "displayName": "TestDG1",
            "groupTypes": [],
            "mail": "testdg1@contoso.com",
            "mailEnabled": true,
            "mailNickname": "TestDG1",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [
                "SMTP:testdg1@contoso.com"
            ],
            "renewedDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
            "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
            "securityEnabled": false,
            "visibility": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
            "owners": []
        }
    ]
}
```

B) Querying for the DL's owners directly:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF/owners

I got a successful response, but the value array is empty:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": []
}
```

5. Interestingly, I can retrieve the members without problems:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF/members

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "Contoso Administrator",
            "givenName": "Admin",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "admin@contoso.com",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
            "surname": "Contoso",
            "userPrincipalName": "admin@contoso.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or by expanding members:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF?$expand=members

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
    "id": "01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "classification": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
    "creationOptions": [],
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "TestDG1",
    "groupTypes": [],
    "mail": "testdg1@contoso.com",
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "TestDG1",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "preferredDataLocation": null,
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:testdg1@contoso.com"
    ],
    "renewedDateTime": "2018-10-15T18:38:08Z",
    "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
    "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": null,
    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
    "members": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "ageGroup": null,
            "businessPhones": [],
            "city": null,
            "companyName": null,
            "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
            "country": null,
            "createdDateTime": null,
            "department": null,
            "displayName": "Contoso Administrator",
            "givenName": "Admin",
            "jobTitle": null,
            …
            …
            … // and all its properties
        }
    ]
}
```

So is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, where do I report it?

Comment: I can reproduce this too. So it should be bug. For bug, you can report it in the Github issue list and label it as bug. For none-bug dev issues, post them on StackOverFlow. For feature request, post them on UserVoice.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_owners

Comment: Ok thanks. I reported the issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/issues/186

Comment: Seiya Su, did I log the bug in the correct place? How soon will this be picked up?

Comment: Let me see if I can find a PM who knows the answer to this question.  This is the right place to file these service bugs.  GitHub is an option for SDK bugs but as this is a service issue, here is the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (as 2019-04-18), owners for mail-enabled security groups and distribution lists are not currently included in `owners` in Microsoft Graph. Owners are currently available only for security groups (not mail-enabled), and Office 365 groups.